# How to set align and width simultaneously in textile?

Tags: redmine, textile

Hello everyone.

I am using redmine wiki and wonder how to set width and align simultaneously. When I use table I wrote this way..

```
|_.No|_.Date|_.Text|
|{width:100px}.1|{width:100px}.2015/12/07|{width:100px}.meeting at school|
```

Above code works properly. But in this code, the number content aligns left. What I want is set width and set align center(=.) simultaneously. I tried like this...

```
|_.{width:100px}.No|_.{width:100px}.Date|_.{width:100px}.Text|
|1|2015/12/07|meeting at school|
```

But only the first option applied.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is an unnecessary dot

```
|_.{width:100px}. header 1 |
```

To set width and alignment simultaneously try

```
|_{width:100px}. header 1 |
```

The same applies for column- and row-spans

```
|_/3{width:100px}. header 1 |
```

The above spans a table header cell over three rows with a width of 100 pixels.

Putting the alignment near the dot, like in the following example will not work.

```
|{width:50px}>. data |
```

The correct order seems to be

```
 |<align><span><width>.  |
```

e.g.

```
 |</2\3{width:40px}.  value |
```